# Unable to run Genymotion on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, genymotion

I have installed the latest Genymotion version (for Ubuntu 16.04) on my Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, but when I start Google Nexus virtual device I get following error:

```
Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: Invalid argument
nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000004 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: Invalid argument
nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 2 relocs 0
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: Invalid argument
nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000005 00000004 00000004 00000000
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: Invalid argument
nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 1 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000
```

I don't know if it is caused by this mismatch or some other problem. Could some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my system also. I solved the problem by using NVIDIA binary driver instead of Nouveau display driver. To change the driver, go to 'Software & Updates' then click on the 'Additional Drivers' and choose 'Using NVIDIA binary driver - version xxx.xx from nvidia-xxx.' Then, click on the 'Apply Changes' button.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Rstudio (it is quite famous bug on rstudio)

It was proposed by someone to run it using the following command in terminal:

```
QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 rstudio
```

so, in your case i think:

```
QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 genymotion
```